# Angularjs binding value from service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I wish to share a service value between one or more controllers (only one in the following example but that's not the point).

The problema is that the value hold in the service is not bound and shown in the view.

The code (derived from angularjs basic service example) is:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
angular.
module('myServiceModule', []).
    controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'notify','$log', function($scope, notify, $log) {
    $scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
        notify.push(msg);
    };

    $scope.clickCount = notify.clickCount();
    $log.debug("Click count is now", $scope.clickCount);
    }]).
factory('notify', ['$window','$log', function(win,$log) {
    var msgs = [];
    var clickCounter = 0;
    return {
        clickCount: function() {
            clickCounter = msgs.length;
            $log.debug("You are clicking, click count is now", clickCounter);
            return clickCounter;
            },
        push: function(msg) {
                msgs.push(msg);
                clickCounter = msgs.length;
                $log.debug("Counter is", clickCounter);
                if (msgs.length === 3) {
                win.alert(msgs.join('\n'));
                msgs = [];
                }
            }
        }
    }]);
```

I wish the counter to be displayed on page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example - example-services-usage-production</title>


<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="myServiceModule">
<div id="simple" ng-controller="MyController as self">
<p>Let's try this simple notify service, injected into the controller...</p>
<input ng-init="message='test'" ng-model="message" >
<button ng-click="callNotify(message);">NOTIFY</button>
<p>(you have to click {{3-self.clickCount}} times more to see an alert)</p>
</div>
<div>You have clicked {{clickCount}} times</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See it in action on [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/VTEdqNqx9cp11HGM)

UPDATE: corrected the trivial errors is html and service code as suggested by @SehaxX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your HTML is wrong. Your last div is not in the div of Controller, and you dont need the self.

```
<body ng-app="myServiceModule">
   <div id="simple" ng-controller="MyController">
     <p>Let's try this simple notify service, injected into the controller...</p>
     <input ng-init="message='test'" ng-model="message" >
     <button ng-click="callNotify(message);">NOTIFY</button>
     <p>(you have to click {{3-self.clickCount}} times more to see an alert)</p>
     <div>You have clicked {{clickCount}} times</div>
  </div>    
</body>
```

Also in your service you are missing return:

```
clickCount: function() {
            clickCounter = msgs.length;
            $log.debug("You are clicking, click count is now", clickCounter);
            return clickCounter;
          },
```

And in your controller you only once call the notify.clickCount() so you need to add it to the method:

```
$scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
      notify.push(msg);
      $scope.clickCount = notify.clickCount();
      $log.debug("Click count is now", $scope.clickCount);
    };
```

Here also a working [code pen](https://codepen.io/SehaxX/pen/zMoEPp) with "Controller as self" if you want. But then in controller you must use this and not $scope.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268051/angularjs-binding-value-from-async-service also